# Adding multiple ttf fonts to HTML2PDF and switching between them via css

Tags: html, css, pdf, fonts, html2pdf

I am using HTML2PDF and so far am having great results. I have stumbled upon a problem that I am wasting lots of time trying to solve.

I am using HTML2PDF v4.0 and I have managed to set the default font for my PDF's to a ttf font that I converted (into 3 files, .z .php and .ufm) These files were placed into the TCPDF fonts directory and the system recognizes them and the final PDF is generating with the correct font.

Now, the style guide I am working from specifies 2 different fonts. I need to use ANOTHER ttf font (also converted and placed into the TCPDF folder and verified by setting it as the default font)

I am having trouble finding a strategy for implementing this scenario into HTML2PDF. I am about to go down the road of splitting the ob_start() buffering into sections for each required font, then re-setting the font between outputs. A simple CSS class would be so much easier but I am unable to get this to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

After half a day of head scratching over this I managed to finally get it to work.
I have converted both of the ttf fonts using the web utility I mentioned in the question above. Then I was able to set a default font for the whole page using

```
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont("helvetica45light");
```

Then when I need to use the other font I just set an inline style similar to the following

```
<span style="font-family:helvetica65medium">some text here</span>
```

I went 1 step further, and created the classes as I was originally hoping for.

```
<style> 
.helvetica65medium{
  font-family:helvetica65medium;
}
.helvetica45light{
  font-family:helvetica45light;
}
</style>
```

now I can just set the class of the text that I want in either of the defined fonts.

I guess I will count that as a lesson learnt